# Python: Bind window position to another window

Tags: python, windows, winapi

I am using PyQt4 on Windows 7 to create an translucent Window only containing a few transparent rectangles. This is for highlighting some stuff on the underlaying window which is not created by my Python app.

The code I am using for positioning my app on top off the other one, make it transparent and clickthrough is

```
class Overlay(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)

        # init translucent window with no frame:
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

        # make it clickthrough:
        hwnd = pywintypes.HANDLE(int(self.winId()))
        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE, win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT)

        other_window = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'Some Program')
        rect = win32gui.GetWindowRect(other_window)
        self.setGeometry(*rect)
```

So my window is positioned exactly on top off the other one.

I am trying to figure out how to make my Python app's window stick to the other program's window and move, resize, minimize and maximize with it. Is this at all possible?

Thanks for your help!